# Infinite Product Expansion of Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: analysis, infinite-product, hyperbolic-functions, weierstrass-factorization

the following equation is from "[1970] Goodson - Distributed system simulation using infinite product expansions":

\begin{align*}
 \cosh z + \left( c z+ \frac{d}{z} \right) \sinh z & = (1 + d)  \displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{z^2}{p_n^2} \right)\\
\tan p_n & = \frac{p_n}{c p_n^2 - d}, \quad p_n \ge 0, \text{real}
\end{align*}

I am not sure if $p_n \ge 0$ is correct, I guess it is $p_n >0$ instead. Maybe someone can give a reference (e.g. a book) where to find the derivation of this equation (or just the equation itself)? This would help me a lot!

Best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansion is a nice example of the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Two well known factorization examples are

$$ \sinh(z) = z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(
 1 + \frac{z^2}{(\pi\, n)^2}\right), \quad
 \cosh(z) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(
 1 + \frac{z^2}{(\pi\, n -\pi/2)^2}\right). $$

Define functions

$$ w = g(z) := \coth^{-1}( c z + d/z) $$

and

$$ f(z) := \cosh(z) + (c z + d/z) \sinh(z). $$

Now

$$ f(z) = \cosh(z) + \coth(w) \sinh(z)= \sinh(z+w)/\sinh(w). $$

As a power series

$$ f(z) = (1 + d) + (3 + 6 c + d) z^2/3! + 
(5 + 20 c + d) z^4/5! + O(z^6). $$

Get the zeros of $\, f(z)\,$ for its infinite product expansion as follows. Let
$\, p_n \approx (n-1)\, \pi \,$ with $\,n>1\,$
be the $n$-th root of $\, f(i\,t). \,$
That is, $\, f(i\, p_n) = 0. \,$

Note that the first root
$\, p_1 \approx \pi/2. \,$
The Weierstrass factorization theorem implies that

$$\, f(z) = (1 + d) \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(
 1 + \frac{z^2}{p_n^2}\right)  $$

with decent convergence. Since
$\, f(i\, u) = \sinh(i\, u + w)/\sinh(w) = 0 \,$
iff $\, w = - i\, u + i\, n \pi, \,$ make the
substitution $\, z = i\, t, \,$ to get

$$ \tan(u) = i \tanh(w) = 1 / (c\, z + d / z) = 1 / (c\, t - d / t) = t / (c\, t^2 - d). $$

Now let $\, u = p_n\,$ to finally get

$$ \tan(p_n) = p_n / (c\, p_n^2 - d). $$

Comment: Why is it $O(z^5),$ not $O(z^4)?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for catching that mistake! I have added one more term anyway.